# Configuring Spring-Boot Autowired JdbcTemplate with Derby

Tags: java, jdbc, annotations, spring-boot, derby

I have cloned a copy of [gs-relational-data-access-complete](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) onto my workspace, downloaded a standalone copy of [Apache Derby](http://mirrors.whoishostingthis.com/apache//db/derby/db-derby-10.12.1.1/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.zip) and launched it "./bin/startNetworkServer".

I want to point my Spring Boot project to use an external instance of Apache Derby instead of the default embedded H2 database that Spring Boot uses. To save time I would like to use the Spring Boot @Autowired annotation.

When I launch a fresh copy of Derby there is no issue:

> ./bin/startNetworkServer
>
> Sat Nov 21 11:11:06 GMT 2015 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
>
> Sat Nov 21 11:11:06 GMT 2015 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.12.1.1 - (1704137) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527

**The problem arises when I launch the Spring Boot application:**

> 2015-11-21 11:55:07.312 **ERROR** 11361 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver@db9d03fc returned null for URL:jdbc:derby://10.12.1.1:1527/example1;create=true;user=test1;password=pass1
>
> at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:326) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]

Any help on how to resolve this issue while still taking advantage of the Spring Boot @Autowired annotation would be greatly appreciated.

My workspace is as follows:

```
pom.xml
src/main/java/hello
----Application.java
----Customer.java
src/main/resources
----application.properties
```

*pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-relational-data-access</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*application.properties:*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://10.12.1.1:1527/example1;create=true;user=test1;password=pass1
spring.datasource.username=test1
spring.datasource.password=pass1
```

*Application.java:*

```
package hello;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: That JDBC URL looks weird to me. Maybe [the doc](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html) would help (or [the examples](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102))?

Comment: there is no "default H2 embedded" database. Whatever embedded database you add to your project will be auto-configured by default (H2, HSQL, Derby). So if you just add derby we'll auto-configure it for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mismatch:

```
Driver:org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver@db9d03fc returned null 
for URL:jdbc:derby://10.12.1.1:1527/example1;create=true;user=test1;password=pass1
```

You're specifying to use the Derby **embedded** driver, but you've given Derby a **client-server** URL for the database.

Derby is detecting that mismatch and refusing your connection attempt.

If you want to use a **client-server** URL, you need to use the Derby ClientDriver class, and you need to have derbyclient.jar in your CLASSPATH.

If you want to use the **embedded** driver, you need to use an embedded driver URL, such as

```
jdbc:derby:example1;create=true;user=test1;password=pass1
```

Comment: I accept that this resolves the specific issue, thank you! The required library was in the derby lib folder.

I added the following to application.properties: 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Comment: I am now getting a different problem, but will open it in a different question. 2015-11-21 20:43:35.633  INFO 4773 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: Application startup failed java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Comment: By switching to h2 and editing pom.xml and application.properties ive resolved all the issues and the project now runs without issues.
pom.xml: " <dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>"
application.properties: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.13.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in the configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby://10.12.1.1:1527/example1;create=true
spring.datasource.username=test1
spring.datasource.password=pass1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

The problem is that derby dependency is for embedded database, you need the client dependency.